# Increase size of Shape by counting characters in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, user-interface, character

In C++, how could I increase size of a Shape by counting characters in an array?

This is a very elementary-level question, however the backings behind it due to my framework are limited; this question will be narrowed down to prevent confusion, as I've already done all the other necessary back-end work.

Explanation:

I'm working in a UI right now creating a rectangle. Easy, right? Well, I'm gathering the character size by using the `strlen()` condition. Since I'm working with pixels, I'm making an estimate that each character will have a max size of (approx) 5 pixels in width.

How could I possibly check by each character, then add 5 to it, and return an output with the overall correct size?

An idea I had was to just make an array, check the position, then if the position was equal to the length for every value then simply += 5, but it and my other attemps failed numerous times.

**Attempt:**

[image]

As you can see, there's a lot of space to the right. Obviously, given that I'm not working exactly pixel-perfect there will be space, however I don't think **that** much is necesary.

Comment: Which framework are you using? Those aren't fixed size fonts so you can't calculate based on string length.

Comment: I switched the fonts over to a mono-spaced font. It helps, actually.

Comment: normally there is a function to calculate the string width in frameworks.